# Apache Ignite CacheEntryListenerException when continuous query active

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm trying to test out continuous queries to see what performance is like, and only just started.  I'm however getting errors (not exceptions) when running my program that's inserting data.  Google search didn't give me anything I recognized as an answer.

Below is the output I get in console window for my console app.

For the server side I'm running just the example code that comes with version 2.3.0.  If I run my app while the continuous query from the example isn't running then there are no errors.  I've put the example code at the end for reference.

```
Record: 286
Record: 287
Dec 13, 2017 12:03:40 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: CacheEntryEventFilter failed: javax.cache.event.CacheEntryListenerExcept
ion: Failed to deploy the filter because it has been closed.
Record: 288
Record: 289
Record: 290
Dec 13, 2017 12:03:40 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: CacheEntryEventFilter failed: javax.cache.event.CacheEntryListenerExcept
ion: Failed to deploy the filter because it has been closed.
Record: 291
Dec 13, 2017 12:03:40 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: CacheEntryEventFilter failed: javax.cache.event.CacheEntryListenerExcept
ion: Failed to deploy the filter because it has been closed.
```

My code for console app

```
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ContQueryTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string CacheName = "dotnet_cache_continuous_query";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            using (var ignite = Ignition.StartFromApplicationConfiguration())
            {
                var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>(CacheName);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Record: {(i.ToString())}");
                        cache.Put(rnd.Next(0, 200), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example code:

```
public class ContinuousQueryExample
    {
        /// <summary>Cache name.</summary>
        private const string CacheName = "dotnet_cache_continuous_query";

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the example.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var ignite = Ignition.StartFromApplicationConfiguration())
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(">>> Cache continuous query example started.");

                var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>(CacheName);

                // Clean up caches on all nodes before run.
                cache.Clear();

                const int keyCnt = 20;

                for (int i = 0; i < keyCnt; i++)
                    cache.Put(i, i.ToString());

                var qry = new ContinuousQuery<int, string>(new Listener<string>(), new ContinuousQueryFilter(15));

                // Create new continuous query.
                using (cache.QueryContinuous(qry))
                {
                    // Add a few more keys and watch more query notifications.
                    for (var i = keyCnt; i < keyCnt + 5; i++)
                        cache.Put(i, i.ToString());

                    // Wait for a while while callback is notified about remaining puts.
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(">>> Example finished, press any key to exit ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback for continuous query example.
        /// </summary>
        private class Listener<T> : ICacheEntryEventListener<int, T>
        {
            public void OnEvent(IEnumerable<ICacheEntryEvent<int, T>> events)
            {
                foreach (var e in events)
                    Console.WriteLine("Queried entry [key=" + e.Key + ", val=" + e.Value + ']');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a full exception details?

Comment: Are you sure this is an exception? It looks like error output (could be ignored) because the node with ContinuousQueryExample has left a cluster.

Comment: You're right they were errors from ignite, not exceptions.  Would be curious what the error is about.  I managed to get rid of it for this specific test by changing the ConQueryTest console app I made to a client (was connecting as server node).  I've made a separate example now where I get the error in Server console window when I have a client app create and apply the filter.  Nothing has left the cluster though, all are still connected in both cases.

Comment: Figured it out.  Needed the implementation of ICacheEntryEventFilter used for the query to exist in both projects.

Comment: Actually, the filter should be automatically created and deployed by the Apache Ignite to all nodes once it is created at one node. Do you have peerAssemblyLoadingMode="CurrentAppDomain" igniteConfiguration attribute at your console app?

Comment: Looks like default is disabled for that so no I wouldn't have it set.

Comment: `peerAssemblyLoadingMode` works only for Compute so it would not help for continuous queries. So yes, you have to make sure that corresponding assembly (dll) is loaded on all server nodes.